# How to use PAM to allow 'root' access only from local terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, root, pam

I am new to `PAM` and its quite complex to pinpoint a specific module or config file, thus asking this.

I want to allow `root` access only from the console i.e if someone is physically present on that system. When someone tries any ways of remote login to `root`(even if he has the correct password) like ssh, telnet, etc(any means), it should not be allowed.

Only when the console is accessed, the `root` access should be granted on correct password.

How do i achieve this by using `PAM` ?

Comment: What operating system / flavour are you using?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/733819/enable-root-to-console-login-only-and-restrict-ssh-login-for-root-only

Comment: I guess the question is to use PAM module and specifically  `pam_securetty.so`  as an authentication prerequisite. Of course is `PermitRootLogin no` the easier way.

Comment: Hi @ValentinBajrami,  I am using Ubutu 22.04.2.

Comment: @sword please see: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/restrict-console-login.en.html

Comment: @ValentinBajrami , for changing the /etc/securetty file, when I type command "tty" from local terminal, it shows "/dev/pts/x" where x is some number. When I ssh into the machine, same is the syntax. How do we distinguish between a local terminal and the terminal wherein I have ssh'ed into the machine ? (so that distinguishing entry I can add into /etc/securetty)

Answer (score 0):

To disable root from remote SSH access, edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` and make sure that you have this line `PermitRootLogin no`. Then restart SSH service.

To disable root from remote Telnet access:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "CONSOLE=/dev/console" > /etc/default/login'
```

Comment: I wish to not only block ssh and telnet, but any other means to remote login. Is there any common authentication config file via which we can only give access to root if local terminal is opened and not via any other remote terminal(be it any service, not just ssh or telnet) ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ssh changes - updating /etc/securetty may be needed to limit root to just console (no tty and vc types).

Comment: Could you please tell which line to be added in this file ? I tried ssh'ing and the terminal form where I have done ssh, and the local terminal, both have the syntax "/dev/pts/x" where x is some number. Unable to distinguish remote and local terminal.

Comment: If you create an empty /etc/securetty file than no root access for local terminals will be allowed with the exception of when the system is in single user mode.    To allow a terminal to be considered secure add the names - tty1  tty2-6 vc/1   - one name per line I believe.

Comment: Well, that is the issue. I am not able to specify a terminal name because say tty1 is local and tty2 is ssh terminal[remote terminal], the number X in ttyX is dynamically assigned and there is no way for me to distinguish a local vs remote terminal from the terminal name.